# How to get wednesday to wednesday dates in php

Tags: php

I am doing one small project and my client need Wednesday to  Wednesday daily report button..

example:
Today Tuesday..So he needs button like these..
Last week wednesday(7-02-2018)
Lastweek thursday(8-02-2018)
lastwek friday(9-02-2018)
Last week saturday(10-02-2018)
last Sunday(11-02-2018)
Yesterday(12-02-2018)
Today(13-02-2018)

And I tried,but it shows only  near days..Can any one help me to get these dates dynamicaly..

```
function closestDate($day){
    $day = ucfirst($day);
    if(date('l', time()) == $day)
        return date("Y-m-d", time());
    else if(abs(time()-strtotime('next '.$day)) < abs(time()-strtotime('last '.$day)))
        return date("Y-m-d", strtotime('next '.$day));
    else
        return date("Y-m-d", strtotime('last '.$day));
}
echo closestDate('saturday');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create code like this

```
    date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 week"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Today tuesday,So the code will give next one week,I need exactle wednesday to tuesday..for one week..

Comment: date($curren_date, strtotime("+1 week"));